# syntax error, unexpected '<'

Tags: php

Seriously

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' on line 22

Code snippet from line 22:

```
<?php
//Submitting to ourselves via POST
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>"/>
?>
```

Try this:

This is not working either:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" />
```

Comment: I just realized i was coding on the same form inside of the <?php ?> code block, instead of putting the form outside for the html.

Comment: Remember to HTML-encode all non-HTML strings echoed into text content and attribute values with `htmlspecialchars`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have html code inside your PHP block

do this:

```
<?php ?>
//Submitting to ourselves via POST
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>"/>
```

or just remove the first line entirely

Comment: "//Submitting to ourselves via POST" will show in the markup in your case, and on the site as well, as this is a php comment, not an html one.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that I was coding my html code inside the <?php section ?> instead of out of the php section, thanks for the heads up with the comment that made me find this error.

Answer (score 4):

Only PHP code should be between `<?php` and `?>`.

Remove the outer PHP tags:

```
<!-- Submitting to ourselves via POST -->
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>"/>
```

**Update:**

I also changed the comment to an HTML comment. You don't want it showing up on the page. You could also just remove the comment, or do this:

```
<?php // Submitting to ourselves via POST ?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>"/>
```

If you have HTML where PHP is expecting PHP code, you will get unexpected '<' errors, and if you have PHP where there should be HTML, it will show up on the webpage, unexecuted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> < form action=" < ?php $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post">

Answer (score 0):

By the way, submitting to yourself can be:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```